# How to use hooks in Headless JS function with react-native-firebase?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I received notification in background, I tried to get data from server with apollo-hooks and react-native-firebase.

And I created new function and registerHeadlessTask.

But It occurs `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.`

react-native: 0.59.8
react-native-firebase: 5.5.6
react-apollo-hooks: 0.4.5

I tried to get data with react-apollo-hooks, but it occurs error.
And, I get another context's custom hook, it occurs `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.` error, too.

index.js:

```
...
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessage)
```

bgMessage.js:

```
export const bgMessage = message => {
  const [mValue, setMValue] = useTest()
  const {
    data: { type },
  } = message

  switch (type) {
    case 'Installing': {
      setMValue(type)
      displayedNotification(message, FCM_MESSAGES_STATUS.Message)
      return Promise.resolve(message)
    }
    default:
      displayedNotification(message, FCM_MESSAGES_STATUS.Message)
      return Promise.resolve(message)
  }
}

export const useTest = () => {
  const [mValue, setMValue] = useState(null)
  return [mValue, setMValue]
}
```

Is there a way to use hooks here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**bgMessage.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
...
export default async (message) => {
  const [mValue, setMValue] = useState('')
  const {
    data: { type },
  } = message

  switch (type) {
    case 'Installing': {
      setMValue(type)
      displayedNotification(message, FCM_MESSAGES_STATUS.Message)
      return Promise.resolve(message)
    }
    default:
      displayedNotification(message, FCM_MESSAGES_STATUS.Message)
      return Promise.resolve(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but, it occurs `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component` error, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to use hooks in Headless JS. According to the answer to this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30707#issuecomment-760640377) hooks are considered as UI elements and thus not allowed to be used in Headless JS.